# Laravel API Routes Return 404

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.6 and I'm getting HTTP404 responses on existing routes in routes/api.php which I define as follows:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/account/plan', 'Account\BillingController@updatePlan');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->put('/account/plan', 'Account\BillingController@unsubscribe');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->patch('/account/plan', 'Account\BillingController@resubscribe');
```

When I use axios.post() on these routes and include the _method parameter I get a 404 response on the PUT and PATCH routes. I have also tested axios.put()/axios.patch() in place of using post() with and without the inclsion of the _method parameter. I have also confirmed these are being correctly represented by artisan route:list:

```
|        | POST          | api/account/plan                        |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Account\BillingController@updatePlan                 | api,auth:api |
|        | PUT           | api/account/plan                        |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Account\BillingController@unsubscribe                | api,auth:api |
|        | PATCH         | api/account/plan                        |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Account\BillingController@resubscribe                | api,auth:api |
```

Example of the Axios Call:

```
axios.post(url,{_method:"PUT",confirm:"unsubscribe"})
     .then(response => callback(response.data))
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

When I define these same routes as follows they all work as intended:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/account/plan', 'Account\BillingController@updatePlan');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/account/unsubscribe', 'Account\BillingController@unsubscribe');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/account/resubscribe', 'Account\BillingController@resubscribe');
```

I am able to separate endpoints by the request method on other routes I am unsure why these are creating a problem. Can someone explain why I get the 404 responses and how I can avoid them?

Comment: why you don't use `axios.put()` or `axios.patch()`?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases

Comment: Because thats not how laravel routing works. You are supposed to send a post with the _method parameter. I have this working for other resources. I did also test using axios.put() and this still results in a 404

Comment: @M31 that is not entirely true. Its only when you send a form in html that laravel uses method spoofing. The html form doesn't have a put method, hence the need for the hidden _method. When you use axios, use the method you need. axios.put(), axios.delete() etc should work...

Comment: Also make sure your the route in the axios.put('/my_route') starts with a trailing slash (in case you didnt already setup the base url already with axios)

Comment: @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin I still get 404 using axios.put('/api/account/plan',data)

Comment: @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin I tested this with other routes and found that both approaches work using axios.post(uri,{_method:"PUT"}) and axios.put(uri,data) successfully submit the same form on other routes in the same project

Comment: Maybe you need to do `php artisan route:clear`, its strange though.

Comment: @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin unfortunately route:clear didnt change the behavior, good thought though.

Comment: @M31 Did you try debugging your routes with postman? Is this working? Just to make sure on which side the problem lies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it seems you are doing evrything fine maybe by following laravel more strict conventions on defining routes you won't encounter the problem? Try like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/account/plan', 'Account\BillingController@updatePlan');
    Route::put('/account/plan', 'Account\BillingController@unsubscribe');
    Route::patch('/account/plan', 'Account\BillingController@resubscribe');
});
```

Comment: sorry but this didnt change the behavior in testing. I tried moving all the auth:api routes into a single group and it still returns 404 only for these routes in the group

Comment: I assume you are making sure your 'url' variable is correct

Comment: As someone already mentioned you can try to do it with postman, to see if axios is the problem

Comment: this does solve this issue, however only if the middleware group is at the top of the api.php file, maybe specifically before the resource routes which follow. I can reproduce the 404 errors by moving the definition of the group to the end of api.php.

Comment: mmm so you have other routes conflicting with these ones? nvm that doesn't make sense lol